# Chromium keeps crashing on my overclocked Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, chromium, overclocking

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4, with 8GB of RAM. I have overclocked my Pi 4, with over_voltage=6, arm_freq=2000, and gpu_freq=750. However, I have been having a problem with running Chromium. Whenever I try to log into the browser, it doesn't let me. After I log into my Google account, I close the browser. As soon as I try to reopen the browser, I get logged out and have to sign in again (Chromium tells me that the browser didn't "shut down correctly"). I'm not sure whether or not my overclocking settings are the culprit. I have a heat sink and case fan, which starts running once the system gets around 60 degrees Celsius. The system's temperature remains well below the 80 degree temps that cause an overheating warning. So why does my browser keep crashing? What are some debugging steps I can take? How can I fix these issues?

Comment: Based on your question you already suspect the overclocking; so why not just burn a new SD card and undo the overclocking and see if the system is stable.

Comment: the silcon lottery means you can't be certain that 2000Mhz will work on EVERY pi

Comment: @SteveRobillard - why would you need to burn a new SD card?

Comment: @JaromandaX out of an abundance of caution. The OP mentions that chromium does not shut down correctly, The overclocking could have caused other undiscovered side effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm starting to think that my issue is a problem with Chromium, not my Pi. I just installed Firefox on my Pi, and it is working much better than Chromium. I am now able to log in.